# Bootstrap v4 uncollapsible icon to the left of the bootstrap hamburger icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have Bootstrap v4 problem. When the navbar switches to the hamburger icon on small screen, I'd like to add a phone icon so mobile users can easily use it, never scrolling down to the Contact section.

I've been trying to use Bootstrap docs regarding `navbar` and an example from 
[Adding a phone and map icon to the left of the bootstrap hamburger icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910576/adding-a-phone-and-map-icon-to-the-left-of-the-bootstrap-hamburger-icon) (adjusting it to Bootstrap v4 by using `d-md-none` instead of obsoleted `visible-xs`). Also I've read through and tried every suggestion from [Bootstrap 4 align navbar item to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-item-to-the-right) playing with  `mr-*`, `ml-*`, `justify-*`, `float-*` but no success - when I resize viewport to the smaller screen, the icon appears yet it keeps get aligned *under* the brand or hamburger menu icon depending on what I use - `mr-*` or `ml-*`, but I want it to stick to the left of the hamburger icon and do not mess around.

Here is the latest iteration of what I have:

```
<!-- Navbar Start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top scrolling-navbar indigo">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav d-md-none">
         <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="tel:+1234567890"><i class="lnr lnr-phone-handset"></i></a>
         </li>
    </ul>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-controls="main-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="lnr lnr-menu"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#hero-area">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to position your phone icon after the navbar-brand (and before the toggler) in the HTML and then add the classes `d-block d-lg-none ml-auto mr-3` to it.

`d-block` will show it by default i.e. from the smallest screen size on. `d-lg-none` will hide it for screens that are large (`lg`) and up. `ml-auto` (margin-left:auto) will push it to the right. And `mr-3` is "margin-right 3 units" to give it a bit of spacing.

Here's a working code snippet (click "run code snippet" and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav d-block d-lg-none ml-auto mr-3">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="tel:+1234567890"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Note that I used a fresh, clean navbar for the code snippet above because your code was a bit of mess. So, start with this clean snippet and then add your custom parts one by one constantly making sure that your additions don't break anything.

Comment: Thank you you solution work perfectly per se. Yet I am still struggling with my issue - looks like it is more of а CSS problem than Bootstrap itself: using either of your solutions I get necessary icon but no hamburger while resizing the viewport. When I add that navbar-header (which is third-party CSS) I have exactly the same situation as in the very beginning: both icons appear but phone keeps get aligned under brand... Anyway, thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

There is no `navbar-header` class in Bootstrap 4. Instead do this..

- Move the `navbar-brand` out of `navbar-header`
- Change `navbar-header` to `ml-auto d-flex flex-nowrap`

This will put the icon and hamburger together on the right in a flexbox div that doesn't wrap. I also added small margin to the right of the phone icon (`mr-2`) but that's optional.

https://www.codeply.com/go/dLJ5GyyAQV

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top scrolling-navbar indigo navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img class="img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/100x30" alt=""></a>
        <div class="ml-auto d-flex flex-nowrap">
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-md-none">
                <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll mr-2" href="tel:+1234567890"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-controls="main-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#hero-area">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, @ZimSystem and @WebDevBooster - both of your solutions work perfectly per se. Yet I am still struggling with my issue - looks like it is more of а CSS problem than Bootstrap itself: using either of your solutions  I get necessary icon but no hamburger while resizing the viewport. When I add that `navbar-header` (which is third-party CSS) I have exactly the same situation as in the very beginning: both icons appear but phone keeps get aligned _under_ brand... Anyway, thank you for helping